# How do I read each line of a file and store it in separate variables using C?

Tags: c

My input file contains the following :

```
w 7b034d90
r 7b034c68
r df84d4
```

How do I read and store the first character into a variable and the second in another variable ? This has to be done for several lines of input.
For e.g I need to store w into variable `A` and 7b034d90 into variable `B` . This has to be done for several thousand lines and the first character of each line will be either w or r. What is the best way of going about this ?

Here is my code :

```
struct MemBlock
{
    char address
    char ReadorWrite;
};

struct MemBlock blocks[100]


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int line = 0;


    static const char filename[] = "sampleTest.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );


    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error opening the file\n\n'");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {

        if (argc == 3)
        {
         for (i=0,i<100,i++)
         {
             while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) 
          {
             r = fscanf(fp, "%s %s\n", blocks[i].ReadOrWrite, blocks[i].address);
             line++;
          }
         }


    fclose(fp);

    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on arrays, structures, and in this case, possibly dynamic allocation.  When you have specific code that's broken, we can help you fix it.

Comment: fgets(), sscanf().... ???

Comment: use a loop and split each line using sscanf

Comment: @MojoJojo58 Welcome to Stack Overflow!  As Oli and Scott point out, before posting a question here we ask that you that you try to do a search for the answer yourself (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Then try to implement it!  This particular question will have lots of answers in a Google search.  If you are still having trouble after that, please post the code of what you have tried in the question and then we can help you out.  Good luck!

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to C and I have to dynamically allocate the hex address to a char of a struct. I am not able to go about it though. I just put my code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many pairs of  you have, you will need to keep track of them via some mechanism.  One would be to malloc and link them into a list.  In order to do this, add a pointer to the struct.

So the flow would be something like the pseudo-code below.  It will need the struct definition, error code, the API file calls to be correct, and make sure that the linked list is correct.

```
struct Memblock head;  
struct Memblock *oldp = &head;
main() {  
    fp = fopen(file);  
    while (fgets(line, fp, sizeof(line)-1) != NULL) {  
        if (sscanf(line, "%c %d", &flag, &address) == 2) {  
            sp = malloc(sizeof(struct));  
            sp->flag = flag;  
            sp->address = address;    
            sp->next = NULL;
            oldp->next = sp;  
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume OP wants an array of `struct MemBlock` when done

C pseudo code (error handling omitted)

```
struct MemBlock {
  unsigned long address;   // Data is obviously hexadecimal
  char ReadorWrite;
};

FILE *inf = fopen(filename, "rt");  // Use "rt"
size_t line = 0;
char buffer[1+1+16+2+100]; // big enough for expected letter and number + change
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, inf) != NULL) line++;
frewind(inf);
struct MemBlock *Array = calloc(line, sizeof *Array);
for (size_t i = 0; i< line; i++) {
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, inf) != NULL)) handle error
  if (2 !=sscanf("%c%lx", &Array[i].ReadorWrite, &Array[i].address)) handle error
}
fclose(inf);
// Use Array[] with length `line`.
...
free(Array)
```

---

I like the one-pass link list idea, but wanted to offer another POV.

Answer (score 0):

There are two many method like `sscanf()` or use `strchr()` or in c++, something like http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/example/tut3.cpp